# How to retrieve relations of type `route=bicycle` with OSMNX?

Tags: python, openstreetmap, geopandas, osmnx

I would like to extract several bike touring routes from Open Street Map using the OSMNX package.
For example, [this bike route](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/8695368#map=11/45.7390/-0.2527) has the property `type=route` and `route=bicycle`. However since they are Relations and not Ways, I cannot use the functions in the OSMNX [Features module](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-reference.html#module-osmnx.features):

Is there a different way to extract this data ?

My attempt using the Features module:

```py
import osmnx as ox
ox.__version__ # '1.5.1'

tags = {"route": "bicycle"}
gdfox = ox.features_from_place("Charente-Maritime", tags)
gdfox.shape  # (0,0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a different way to extract this data?

Yes. Per the [OSMnx docs](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting-started.html), the `features` module searches by OSM tags to find matching elements. You're looking for specific relations here, so you should use the `geocoder` module to retrieve them. Per the docs, this module allows you to "retrieve place boundaries or any other OpenStreetMap elements by name or ID." Something like:

```py
import osmnx as ox
ox.settings.log_console = True
ox.geocoder.geocode_to_gdf("R8695368", by_osmid=True)
```

However, there is one caveat: your example relation is [missing](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/lookup?osm_ids=R8695368) in Nominatim itself for some reason. This has happened before ([related issue](https://github.com/osm-search/Nominatim/issues/2752)), and it may be worth you inquiring directly with Nominatim on Github if it is missing.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I checked a dozen of bike routes in France and Europe and not one was referenced in Nominatim. I will check with them.

Comment: After further investigation it seems like Relations of type route in particular are harder to include in Nominatim https://github.com/osm-search/Nominatim/issues/413